# Not Receiving Expected Redux State on Initial Render

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a social media application where the `commentCount` value of each post is not being rendered initially.

[image: post upon initialization]

Redux Dev Tools tells me, that our post objects are not receiving `commentCount`

[image: post object not receiving commentCount]

Only after triggering a `like` or `unlike` action will the `post` object receive the `commentCount`

[image: commentCount value renders after like/unlike action]

[image: post object with commentCount]

This is my dataReducer

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  post: {},
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOADING_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case SET_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case LIKE_POST:
    case UNLIKE_POST:
            let index = state.posts.findIndex(
        (post) => post.postId === action.payload.postId
            );
            state.posts[index] = action.payload;
            if (state.post.postId === action.payload.postId) {
                state.post = {...state.post, ...action.payload}
            }
      return {
        ...state
      };
    case SET_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: action.payload
      };

    ...
  }
}
```

These are my dataActions

```
export const getPosts = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA });
  axios
    .get('/posts')
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_POSTS,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_POSTS,
        payload: []
      });
    });
};

export const likePost = (postId) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .get(`/post/${postId}/like`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: LIKE_POST,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

export const unlikePost = (postId) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .get(`/post/${postId}/unlike`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: UNLIKE_POST,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Network Tab
[image: network tab]

Any suggestions on what's going on? Thank you.

Comment: You’re saying the data from the server side isn’t including the comments count? What’s in the network tab?

Comment: Most likely the server isn't returning the commentCount property. Can you check the response JSON?

Comment: Hello @DaveNewton, I just updated the post with a screenshot of the network tab. Yes, the first Redux dev tools screenshot, shows our first post object without the commentCount

Comment: Hey @JoseFelix. Right `commentCount` isn't being returned initially. You can find the JSON response on the Redux Dev Tools screenshot I've posted above.

Comment: The React code isn’t relevant then, no?

Comment: @KennethAP then you or team member will have to update the back-end so it can send you `commentCount`

Comment: @JoseFelix Ah ok, I understand. I'm need to update the `getPosts` handler in the back-end to also return `commentCount`. Thanks!

Comment: @DaveNewtonYou're right.It's not relevant. The issue is I forgot to return the `commentCount` property. Thanks!